# Google maps marker click function not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to assign to every marker an on click event, but it seems not to work

In the page i have google maps and a list of countries that has another list inside (i want that when i click on some marker that list will open as dropdown menu).

My code to initialize google maps:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: centerPos,
      zoom: zoomLevel
    };

map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions );

for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
     marker.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            title: locations[i][0],
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            id: locations[i][3]
    })); 

google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', function() { 
    var id = marker.id;
    if($("#" + id).parent('li').find('ul').css('display') == 'none'){
        $('#country-list li').find('ul').slideUp();
        $("#" + id).slideDown();
    }else{
        $('#country-list li').find('ul').slideUp();
    }

});

}



  }
```

And my code to the drop down list of countries:

```
<ul id="country-list">
                    <?php
                    $blogs = wp_get_sites();
                    foreach($blogs as $blog){
                        if($blog['blog_id'] == 1){}else{
                            switch_to_blog($blog['blog_id']);
                            $details = get_blog_details($blog['blog_id']);
                            echo '<li><img src="'.getOption('opt-country-flag')['url'].'" alt="" /><span>'.getOption('opt-country').'</span>';
                            $Locations =Location::all(array());
                            echo'<ul class="cntry-add" id="'.$blog['blog_id'].'">';
                            foreach($Locations as $Location){
                                echo '<li><span>'.$Location->post->post_title.'</span>';
                                echo'<div>';
                                if($Location->to_array()['telephone']){echo '<strong>'._e( 'Adrress: ', 'investing-academy' ).'</strong><br />'.$Location->to_array()['address'].'<br /><br />';}
                                if($Location->to_array()['telephone']){echo '<strong>'._e( 'Telephone: ', 'investing-academy' ).'</strong><br />'.$Location->to_array()['telephone'];}
                                echo'</div></li>';

                            }
                            echo'</ul>';
                            wp_reset_query();
                            restore_current_blog();
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </ul>
```

The drop down menu is working when i click on each country.
only when i try to click on the marker it's not working.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace

```
var id = marker.id;
```

with

```
var id = this.id;
```